# Hide apps from Launcher

Tags: android, android-launcher

I want to make an application in which we show the list of all apps which is installed in my phone with checkbox. When user checked the any application then that apps should be show on Launcher. Otherwise apps should be hide from Launcher.

Answer (score 3):

Unless you code a launcher app too, it's not possible. Other launcher's will simply look at the apps manifest (using package manager) if it declares launcher intent or not.

In the case where both launcher and settings are in same app, best solution will be to use a shared preferences file:

```
Set<String> blacklistedApps;

//--add package names--
blacklistedApps.put("com.useless.uselessapp");

//--save as a preference--
SharedPreferences.Editor.putStringSet("blacklisted",blacklistedApps).commit();

//--read preference--
blacklistedApps = SharedPreferences.getStringSet("blacklisted",new Set<String>());
```

Comment: @AKJha In android one app (say your app) simply cannot alter behavior of other app (say some launcher app on users device) . Unless both apps are explicitly told to work together by the developer(say you develop your settings app, and also develop a launcher app to work with it).

Comment: Exactly, the launcher app and the settings app both develop by me. And in settings app we want to this functionality.

Comment: @AKJha Sounds suspicious to me.  If you developed the launcher, then what is the problem?  You can show or hide any app you want!  Forgive me, but if you do not know how to do this, then I am struggling to believe that you wrote the launcher.

Comment: @Simon, That is not the problem, But I want to set the Flag on that apps which is checked by user and in Launcher I want to check that flag and show.

Comment: I think what @AKJha meant is to be able to show and hide apps at runtime. i.e. as soon as an app is enabled from Settings - it disappears from launcher. It is easy to do it one time statically by reading the manifest xml - but how to do it at runtime is probably his question is.

Comment: @ KurtCobain, Exactly, this is the issue. I want show and hide apps in run times as u says.